# Boolean Intersect is not working well

Tags: modifiers

I try to do an animation with a cube with intersected parts with two tetrahedrons that move in scale. For This I'm using the Boolean modifier.

The problem is that some parts of the cube pop outside of intersection randomly in the animation.

Some parts pop as well if I select "Exact" solver.

As you can see in the gif.

Is there an solution for this or an alternative to this modifier that can do the same job?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turning on Self intersect and/or Hole tolerant will probably solve the problem, however beware that it will cause a noticible slowdown.

Comment: I tried with Self and/or Hole tolerant it didn't change anything then I got back to solver fast and the bool is now working correctly :/

Comment: But it was glitch. When I repeat it doesn't work.